# Microsoft Graph API - /me/people does not return desired result

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on a project using Microsoft Graph API. This project uses `/me/people` to get data.

[According to Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/people_example): "Microsoft Graph applications can use the People API to retrieve the people who are most relevant to a user. Relevance is determined by the user’s communication and collaboration patterns and business relationships. People can be local contacts, **contacts from social networking or from an organization’s directory**, and people from recent communications (such as email and Skype)."

According to this, I think that the result can be confirmable.

For example, I have 3 users account: user1@tnv.onmicrosoft.com, user2@tnv.onmicrosoft.com, user3@tnv.onmicrosoft.com. I put them in the same AAD security group named AADTestGroup.

I expect that when user1 calls `/me/people`, the result contains user2 and user3. However, it does not returns as expected.

The questions are:

- What am I missing here?
- How could I organize user accounts in O365 to get confirmable result from `/me/people`?
- How long does this function take to reflect changes from Office 365?

Answer (score 2):

Being in the same security group isn't a relevant "communication and collaboration pattern" or "business relationship". Until you have sufficient activity between these users, they will not show up in the result. Try editing the same document, emailing each other, etc. and they will begin to show up.